# Can you install android sdk on a windows 8 pc?

Tags: android, windows-8

Can I install the Android sdk on a Windows 8 pc?
and is it possible to develop apps on Windows 8 pc?

Answer (score 1):

System requirements are pretty clear about it:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

It is possible, if you have at least a recent JDK installed.
Here is the Windows bundle with the SDK and a dedicated Eclipse version:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#win-bundle

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can install android sdk on a windows 8 pc. Its not create any problem.
Nothing any issue in windows 8 pc regrding this.

Answer (score 1):

Window 8 is not listed in System Requirements at http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html.

When I installed ADT 64bit in Win 8 64bit, it didn't worked however ADT 32bit worked fine.

Do install JDK 8 first.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that windows8 is not listed in the system requirements. But ADT runs well in this Operating System. Make sure that you download JDK and set its path. I used JDK 1.7.0_05 which I had been using in my previous version of Windows that is Windows 7. Also make sure that the SDK gets downloaded completely. I am saying that because my SDK Manager was not running and later I realized that the SDK's download remained incomplete. Good Luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Can i install android sdk on a windows 8 pc?
```

Yes, you can , search it on google for how can it be installed, there are many tutorials also available !

```
 Is it possible to develop apps on windows 8 pc?
```

Possible if ur [system requirements](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) are achieved !

If you're a new Android developer, we recommend you download the ADT Bundle to quickly start developing apps. It includes the essential Android SDK components and a version of the Eclipse IDE with built-in ADT (Android Developer Tools) to streamline your Android app development.

With a single download, the ADT Bundle includes everything you need to begin developing apps:

- Eclipse + ADT plugin
- Android SDK Tools
- Android Platform-tools
- The latest Android platform
- The latest Android system image for the emulator

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can develop Android apps on Windows 8 or Windows 8.1. However running the emulator will require your processor to support Intel HAXM (https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) and there is a possibility that you may run into issues here.